# Why two different source code generate same control flow graph in ethereum smart contract?

Tags: solidity, ether, bytecode, vulnerability, code

I analyzed control flow graph of two contracts written in solidity with different source code, one having vulnerability and other after resolving it. https://swcregistry.io/docs/SWC-107#modifier-reentrancysol I took modifier_reentrancy.sol and modifier_reentrancy_fixed.sol to analyze. Both of them had same Control flow graph obtained through EtherSolve.

Comment: Can you share the contract and the flow generated?